# How do I omit part of part of a legal definition with an ellipsis?

Tags: punctuation, ellipses, omissibility

I need to contract the below sentence (it was legalese that I have simplified) to just present (b), but need to indicate that (b) is not the only condition:

> Ending on the earlier of (a) [occurrence] and (b) [date]

Should this be:

> Ending on the earlier of ... and (b) [date]
>
> Ending on the earlier of  ... (b) [date]
>
> Ending on the earlier of (a) ... and (b) [date]

Or something else.

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. There are two terms in the contract and both are valid. The British way of expressing the original would be "Ending on (a) [occurrence] **or** (b) [date] **whichever is the earlier.**

Comment: Several questions here. First, is it a quote? Are you trying to preserve the form the statement as closely as possible? Second... you want to omit the semantic content of the first option (presumably because its meaning doesn't matter in contextualizing the second option) but retain an indication of its presence (presumably because its presence matters in contextualizing the second option). Putting aside the fact that I can't conceive of such a situation, why do you want to do this? To draw attention to b? To remove a because it's bad / distracting / leads to error? Just to save space?

Comment: Also @MDHunter Obviously, the third. The first two do not work. Let us know if you need more help. Good Luck.